# flutter installation on android studio. No main.dart or any files showing up

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, dart, flutter

I am looking for some help! I have installed flutter SDK, ran flutter doctor in flutter CMD, Installed the plug-in on android studio, and opened a new app. When it opens there are no files. No main.dart....nothing really. I think ive messed up the install. Any pointers?

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question. What does "opened a bew app" mean exactly?

Comment: Note that Android Studio's project navigator on the left will show nothing in flutter projects if the "Android" mode is selected because it cannot recognise a valid Android project structure, try switching to "Project".

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It actually all came up after I deleted the the project and re-started Android Studio.

Comment: Answer from @Umbo is correct. Changed the "dropdown" value from "Android" to "Project", solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the project and restarted android studio and now everything appears as it should.

Comment: I am having this issue. Did you just delete the project from disk?

Comment: I deleted it in android studios and then restarted AS.